# jQuery SimpleModal plugin: how to overwrite 'alert' messages

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

Is it possible to overwrite 'alert' messages like this plugin overwrites 'confirm'?

Comment: My bad. Since alert messages are subset of confirmation messages, so it's solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the alert function

```
window.alert = function specailAlert(msg) {
   //some facny code here
}
```